# Strongloop error in slc loopback command

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, strongloop

I've installed Strongloop in my Digital Ocean droplet, but when I try to begin a project with `slc loopback` this error appears:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EACCES, open '/home/cae/apps/easylearn/package.json'
```

I've searched for this error or similar ones, but until now couldn't find anything...
Any tips?

Comment: Did you check the permissions for that file?

Comment: yep apparently it was permissions, just typed sudo chown -R $USER /home/cae/apps/easylearn/ and everything worked, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EACCES` errors typically have to do with bad file/directory permissions. Correct the permissions and the problem should go away.